# Graph API - Get all emails from shared inbox

Tags: azure, rest, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get all emails from a shared mailbox using the Microsoft Graph API.
I have obtained an authorization code and then use the token endpoint to get my bearer token:
[image: Post to get bearer token]

I then try to get the mails from the shared inbox:
[image: Get emails from shared folder]

But I get the following response:
[image: Response]

My API permissions look like this:
[image: API Permissions]

What am I missing? It works fine when getting mails from my own inbox.

Comment: Change the `/users/{user id}` endpoint to the `/me` endpoint and try it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works but that is not what I am interested in :-) I want to read from a shared mailbox, i.e. not my own.

Comment: Then you need application permissions, not delegate permissions.

Comment: Hi,  have you tried the methods provided in my answer? How is the result?

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, you are using `delegated permissions`, so you can only call the `/me` endpoint to get your own email.

If you want to get the email of any user from the shared inbox, then you should use `application permissions`, then you need to use the **client credential flow** to get the token, and then you will be able to use that token to call `/users/{user id}` endpoint.

Comment: So it is not possible to read emails from a shared inbox using delegated permissions? Then what is the delegated Mail.Read.Shared permission for?

Comment: @jlpdk  **Delegated permissions** can only call the `/me` endpoint. The `/users/{user id}` endpoint can only be called by a token that contains **application permissions**, this endpoint is usually used in scenarios where no user is logged in. 
This is true for any azure-ad-graph-api endpoint.

Comment: @jlpdk  I think the `Mail.ReadWrite` **application permissions** should be sufficient, you can try to grant that permission, and then don’t forget to grant the administrator consent. Use that permission and then use the client credential flow to get a token and then call the endpoint to try it out.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will make sure to accept your answer. Do you have a link/some documentation saying that Mail.Read.Shared does not work with delegated permissions?

Comment: @jlpdk  Sorry, I don’t have a similar document, but based on my experience, you can’t use delegated permissions to other users’ emails. `Mail.Read.Shared` is a delegated permission. It can only call the `/me` endpoint to get your own emails. If you try to call the `/users` endpoint with `Mail.Read.Shared` delegated permissions, it will definitely report an error, just like you are experiencing now.

Comment: @jlpdk  Did you use the `application permissions` in the way I provided in the answer? Did the call succeed?

Comment: The problem is I am not allowed application permissions but need access to a shared mailbox - so that is tricky :) Pretty certain application permissions will work though.

Comment: @jlpdk  Can `Mail.Read` application permissions be used?

Comment: Problem is, I am not allowed application permissions, so no, they cannot be used unfortunately.